# Will_paginate prev next link unexpected behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I just want to apply custom style for the next/prev page

But it works in a stange way.

The **previous link** will be **disappeared** after clicking the next link, vice versa.

link => http://great-compassion.com:1234/news/index

#### The  snippet of  will_pagination

```
def page_number(page)
  unless page == current_page
    tag(:li, link(page, page, :rel => rel_value(page)))
  else
    tag(:li, page, :class => "current")
  end
end

def previous_or_next_page(page, text, classname)
  if page
    tag(:li, link(text, page), :class => classname)
  else
    tag(:li, text, :class => classname + ' disabled')
  end
end

def html_container(html)
  tag(:ul, html, container_attributes)
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The previous link is actually present in the html. You can see it by inspecting the page content. Also, you can hover next to `1` and click on the `Previous page` even though you can't see it.

[image: Screen shot of the inspected page]

The styling applied to it - particularly the `text-indent: -9999px;` is making it not visible. Changing the value of text-indent to 0 or 10 makes it show up.

The culprit styling is from `custom.css`

```
.pagenum .previous_page a {
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url(/assets/images/listbtn.png) -40px 0px;
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
```